# What is the difference between Structured Programming and Object Oriented programming?

Tags: oop, structured-programming

What is the difference between structured programming and object oriented programming?

Comment: Not a good fit for a Q&A site. Taking the word COBOL out of your question would give you a sufficient answer poking into a search-engine.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion !!

Comment: Being snarky, Structured COBOL is in use in the real business applications whereas OO COBOL is not.

Answer (score 0):

Structured COBOL programming is top-down approach whereas Object Oriented COBOL programming is bottom-up approach

Another Example of Objected oriented is Java

Hope it helps:)